# Edit stage history fields

Tags: lightning, field-history

In **lightning** I need a way to custom the 'stage history' fields.
The stage history present the 'amount' field,  and I need to replace it with 'other_custom_opportunity_amount'.

I can't locate the stage history object in the 'Object manager'.

Can I edit the 'stage history' fields?

Thanks,
Aharon

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

To set up field history tracking:

1. From the management settings for the object whose field history you want to track, go to the fields area.
2. Click Set History Tracking.

It's in the top right:
[image]

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history_for_standard_objects.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks for that -  found it.
Now I face another issue - it seems like it doesn't matter which check-boxes values I'll pick -The Opportunity UI present only the following fileds:
Stage, amount , Probability, Revenue, Close date, Last modified by & Last modified

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you add the correct related list to the opportunity layout. Don't use the Stage History related list, but the Opportunity Field History list.